# ColdFusion 2018 - Requests Multiply Executed

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018

with a new project we encountered some strange behaviour on our ColdFusion application.
Whenever a single request is initiated from the browser, the code of the cfml-templates is
executed multiple times. Upon viewing the corresponding log-files we found out, that indeed
for some reason the same request fires the evaluation in our application multiple times. One request
generates several entries. This is especially the case for long-running requests, such as database imports.

The ColdFusion application implements a REST-service, but even on manually requesting a resource,
such as a certain cfml page, on the same application - the code gets executed an unknown amount of times(variable initializations, database write-operations etc. take place), and if the request runs too long (cap at around ~4-6 seconds) there is no response to the browser.

About the infrastructure:
The application is Coldfusion18 with Tomcat Standard Edition
The webserver is an Apache (2.4.6).
Everything runs on a Linux machine with Cent OS 7.7
The corresponding Java version is 11.0.4

Our best guess is that there might be some misscommunication between the coldfusion connector with
the apache webserver. We actually searched for some configuration parameters that could cause the
problem, without success. Upon an installation on a windows machine we did not encounter that error.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: do you have a development/testing environment and does it happen there?

Comment: We first encountered it on our dev-environment, but even with a fresh install on another server for our prod-environment the same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

we just found our answer in the following post:

[Link to Solution](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/02/apache-crashes-serving-multiple-thread-requests-using-cf2018/)